# how to read output from several running processes in python?

Tags: python, redirect, terminal, output

is there any chance to read outputs from running terminals?

I have running processes in /dev/pts/# and I want to read all of them (and then maybe save into a file). 
This is working quite well, but only for one/first process:

```
import subprocess

with open("path_to_file_with_devices_list") as f:
    content = f.read().splitlines()
    for x in content:
        subprocess.check_call(['cat', x]
```

I have whole output from first /dev/pts/# in terminal and I understand this stuck, because script capture first /dev/pts/# and I can see only this output.

How to handle this? I mean, how to capture output from other/next terminal in /dev/pts/#?

Somehow run in other terminal each next process? Or force this script to end each reading and move on further to next one.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the terminal sessions started by a python program or are they independent?  If independent, are they running under the same user ID?

Comment: they are independent and yes - they are running under the same user ID.